Search for currency pairs using Pandas
I am trying to learn more about Python.  Please see the code below:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/crypto?offset=0&count=25")[0]
symbols = df.Symbol.tolist()
test=len(symbols)
for symbol in symbols:
    print(symbol)

The query string has default values.  If I change the query string to:
https://finance.yahoo.com/crypto?offset=5&count=100

Then the same 25 symbols are returned as the first url i.e. the same 25 symbols are returned regardless of the offset or count.  If I browse in a browser then I get the expected results i.e. they vary depending on the offset and count.
Also my reading is telling me that only us cryptos are returned.  Is this correct?

This is probably due to the dynamic nature of the page you're loading. I think what you're seeing is the table's initial state but that subsequently changes (JavaScript actions) which is not observed by the underlying parser (lxml if available or bs4+html5lib). You can probably achieve your objective using a combination of selenium and pandas

here is the logic that they are using to show the results with the new endpoint from Yahoo Finance https://finance.yahoo.com/markets/crypto/all/?count=100&start=100:

count means how much You want to see (eg: you want 100 symbols)
start means where to start (eg: you want 0-100 results for this use count=100&start=0, or you want 100-200 results for this use count=100&start=100)

Also, I noticed this endpoint https://finance.yahoo.com/crypto? with the offset param no longer working and throwing a 404 Not found error, after visiting the sites, I saw they are using this new endpoint https://finance.yahoo.com/markets/crypto/all/ with new param called start.
here is the code:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/markets/crypto/all/?count=100&start=0")[0] # count 100 results from 0-100, if you change 'count=100&after=100' the logic will count 100 results from 100-200
symbols = df.Symbol.tolist()
test=len(symbols)
for symbol in symbols:
    print(symbol)

hope this will help!
